# get Id of current row in Html.ActionLink in for loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which contains Master Data list in grid form and i want to see all the detail of that master record which is clicked in the next page. 
For this i require id of that record in the `html.actionlink` in the loop

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
   {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
                 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("See Detail", "detail", "mycontroller", new { id = (m => m[i].ID) }) 
            //syntax error in above line (m => m[i].ID)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, `new { id = Model[i].ID }` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("See Detail"+i, "detail", "mycontroller", new { id =  model[i].ID })
```

Or You can Try this

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Hidden("@Model[i].ID")
            @Html.Display("@Model[i].Name")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Display("@Model[i].Date")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("See Detail"+i, "detail", "mycontroller", new { id = "@Model[i].ID" }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(item.ID)
                     @Html.DisplayFor(item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(item.Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("See Detail", "detail", "mycontroller", new { id =item.ID) }) 

         }
```